# I want to make parsing program in dashboard using python selenium

Tags: python, parsing, selenium

I am python selenium beginner.
I want to make parsing program from dashboard.

here is my python code

This code can approach first a tag. but it can't go to second, third a tag.
I try to 'anchor_element[1].click()' but it's a wrong code.
I don't know where is wrong

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

url = 'http://www.naver.com'

driver.get(url)

id_input = driver.find_element_by_name('id')
id_input.send_keys('jaeyeon93')

pass_input = driver.find_element_by_name('pw')
pass_input.send_keys('wodus0101')

log_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('btn_login')

log_button.click()

time.sleep(2)
url2 = 'cafe.naver.com/startdata'

driver.get(url2)
#go to dashborad.
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='menuLink0']").click()
#change iframe. dashboard source code is in iframe
board_iframe = driver.find_element_by_id('cafe_main')
driver.switch_to_frame(board_iframe)


anchor_element = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
anchor_element.click()
```

Here is the code I want to click and parsing using loop

```
<iframe name='cafe_main' id='cafe_main'>
<form name='ArticleList'>
    <table class="board-box">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td class='board-list'>
                    <span>
                        <span class='aaa'>
                            <a class="m-tcol-c" onmouseover="" onclick="return dynamicParamLink('/ArticleRead.nhn?clubid=28279768&page=1&boardtype=L&articleid=91&referrerAllArticles=true', event);" href="/ArticleRead.nhn?clubid=28279768&page=1&boardtype=L&articleid=91&referrerAllArticles=true">API Store</a>
                        </span>
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td class='board-list'>
                    <span>
                        <span class='aaa'>
                            <a class="m-tcol-c" onmouseover="" onclick="return dynamicParamLink('/ArticleRead.nhn?clubid=28279768&page=1&boardtype=L&articleid=90&referrerAllArticles=true', event);" href="/ArticleRead.nhn?clubid=28279768&page=1&boardtype=L&articleid=90&referrerAllArticles=true">WikiDocs - Online books platform</a>
                        </span>
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td class='board-list'>
                    <span>
                        <span class='aaa'>
                            <a class="m-tcol-c" onmouseover="" onclick="return dynamicParamLink('/ArticleRead.nhn?clubid=28279768&page=1&boardtype=L&articleid=90&referrerAllArticles=true', event);" href="/ArticleRead.nhn?clubid=28279768&page=1&boardtype=L&articleid=90&referrerAllArticles=true">Third Href</a>
                        </span>
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td class='board-list'>
                    <span>
                        <span class='aaa'>
                            <a class="m-tcol-c" onmouseover="" onclick="return dynamicParamLink('/ArticleRead.nhn?clubid=28279768&page=1&boardtype=L&articleid=90&referrerAllArticles=true', event);" href="/ArticleRead.nhn?clubid=28279768&page=1&boardtype=L&articleid=90&referrerAllArticles=true">4th Href</a>
                        </span>
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
</iframe>
```

Please. Help me.

Answer (score 0):

it only executes once. to do more, you'll need a for loop somewhere

Edit:

Here:

```
for(your_range):
    anchor_element = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
    anchor_element.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the anchor elements with the following code without needing so many queries as you have now in your code:

```
driver.get(url2)
###### New code ########
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//a")
for link in links:
    link.click()
```

Comment: I tried this code,
but first loop is okay but, next loop have a problem

links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//a")
for link in links:
    link.click()
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.back()

but second loop isn't work.

I want to store all a tag in anchor_elements = []
using the anchor_elements = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')

#anchor_elements = []
#anchor_elements = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
#anchor_elements[0].click()
#time.sleep(3)
#driver.back()

#anchor_elements[1].click()
but it can't I don't know why this problems is occured